# Bash - Multiple Commands across multiple lines

Tags: command-line, bash, shell

I have a long Bash command. This command looks something like this:

```
grunt build && mv file1.txt ../../results && mv file2.txt ../../logs && mv file3.txt ../home && mv file4.txt ../../../deployments
```

I'm adding this command to a `README.md` file. I would like to make this a) easy-to-read and b) copy-and-pastable. My question is, how do I make an easy-to-read multi-command line for Bash?

I've tried the following, which did not work:

```
grunt build && \
  mv file1.txt ../../results && \ 
  mv file2.txt ../../logs && \ 
  mv file3.txt ../home && \
  mv file4.txt ../../../deployments
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Explanation

You can continue a command in the next line with backslash (`\`), but only if the backslash is immediately before the newline character terminating the line. In your code there are spaces after few backslashes. Remove them.

Note `&&` at the end of the line [is enough for Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253518/108618) to continue reading the command from the next line, even if there are unquoted, unescaped spaces after `&&`. But not if there is an escaped space, like in your case.

---

#### Examples

This will work:

```
true   && \
echo b   # ^ no space here, newline character immediately after \
```

And this will work:

```
true   &&         
echo b # ^^^^^^^^^ zero or more spaces, they don't matter
```

(Change `true` to `false` to learn `&&` really does its job.)

But this won't work*:

```
true   && \ 
echo b   # ^ escaped space here, it breaks things
```

The escaped space is like a quoted space. This also won't work*:

```
true   && ' '
echo b   # ^ quoted space here, it breaks things
```

---

<sup>* Well, it will work if there's a command named   (literal space) in your OS. This is technically possible, yet very, very uncommon (if I saw such executable, I would smell something fishy right away). Still the snippet *won't work the way you want it to work* because `&&` will connect `true` and  , not `true` and `echo`.</sup>

---

#### Side note

Code like this:

```
foo && \
bar
```

(where `\` properly escapes the newline) is valid, yet redundant. It can be:

```
foo &&
bar
```

Some users don't like any of the above because by inspecting the beginnings of the lines one cannot tell if `bar` should run conditionally or unconditionally. One needs to inspect the end of the first line (that may be quite long) to find the `&&`.

Therefore one may prefer this:

```
foo \
&& bar
```

Here `\` is mandatory, but it's evident `bar` should depend on the previous line, even if the previous line is very long and one doesn't spot the backslash immediately.